# Group by specific element of array with mongo aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to use the aggregation framework to group by a specific element of an array?

Such that with documents like this:

```
{
  name: 'Russell',
  favourite_foods: [
    { name: 'Pizza', type: 'Four Cheeses' },
    { name: 'Burger', type: 'Veggie'}
  ],
  height: 6
}
```

I could get a distinct list of top favourite foods (ie. foods at index 0) along with the height of the tallest person who's top favourite food that is?

Something like this (although it doesn't work as the array index access dot notation doesn't seem to work in the aggregation framework):

```
db.people.aggregate([
  { $group : { _id: "$favourite_foods.0.name", max_height: { $max : "$height" } } }
])
```

Answer (score 17):

Seems like you are relying on the favorite food for each person being first in the array.  If so, there is an aggregation framework operator you can take advantage of.

Here is the pipeline you can use:

```
db.people.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$unwind" : "$favourite_foods"
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "$name",
                "height" : "$height"
            },
            "faveFood" : {
                "$first" : "$favourite_foods"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$faveFood.name",
            "height" : {
                "$max" : "$_id.height"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

On this sample dataset:

```
> db.people.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("508894efd4197aa2b9490741"),
    "name" : "Russell",
    "favourite_foods" : [
        {
            "name" : "Pizza",
            "type" : "Four Cheeses"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Burger",
            "type" : "Veggie"
        }
    ],
    "height" : 6
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5088950bd4197aa2b9490742"),
    "name" : "Lucy",
    "favourite_foods" : [
        {
            "name" : "Pasta",
            "type" : "Four Cheeses"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Burger",
            "type" : "Veggie"
        }
    ],
    "height" : 5.5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5088951dd4197aa2b9490743"),
    "name" : "Landy",
    "favourite_foods" : [
        {
            "name" : "Pizza",
            "type" : "Four Cheeses"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Pizza",
            "type" : "Veggie"
        }
    ],
    "height" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50889541d4197aa2b9490744"),
    "name" : "Augie",
    "favourite_foods" : [
        {
            "name" : "Sushi",
            "type" : "Four Cheeses"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Pizza",
            "type" : "Veggie"
        }
    ],
    "height" : 6.2
}
```

You get these results:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "Pasta",
            "height" : 5.5
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Pizza",
            "height" : 6
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Sushi",
            "height" : 6.2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: if name is not unique you can use _id in its place in the first $group.

Comment: Nice solution, but it relies on the documents produced by unwind retaining their sorted order - can you rely on this and is it documented somewhere as such?

Comment: I know that is how it works from multiple trials, and while it's not in the docs, I did look at the source code and it appears to be the case. see: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pipeline/document_source_unwind.cpp

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it isn't currently possible to extract a specific element from an array in aggregation:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589

Comment: you can't extract an arbitrary element by position, you happen to have a way to get first or last via $unwind and re-$group with $first or $last operator.

Comment: **Good News**: That issue was eventually resolved with [the $arrayElementAt operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

Answer (score 3):

**JUST add more information about the result after using `"$wind"`:**

**DOCUMENT :**

```
> db.people.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("508894efd4197aa2b9490741"),
    "name" : "Russell",
    "favourite_foods" : [
        {
            "name" : "Pizza",
            "type" : "Four Cheeses"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Burger",
            "type" : "Veggie"
        }
    ],
    "height" : 6
},
...
```

**AGGREAGATION :**

```
db.people.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$favourite_foods"
}]);
```

**RESULT :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("508894efd4197aa2b9490741"),
    "name" : "Russell",
    "favourite_foods" :{
            "name" : "Pizza",
            "type" : "Four Cheeses"
    },
    "height" : 6
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("508894efd4197aa2b9490741"),
    "name" : "Russell",
    "favourite_foods" : {
            "name" : "Burger",
            "type" : "Veggie"
    },
    "height" : 6
}
```

**In Addition:**
If there are more than two array fields in one collection record, 
we can use [**"$project"**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) stage to specify the array field.

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "favourite_foods": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$favourite_foods"
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make use of the $project and $unwind operators (let me know if this isn't what you're trying to accomplish):

```
> db.people.aggregate(
   {$unwind: "$favourite_foods"}, 
   {$project: {food : "$favourite_foods", height: 1}}, 
   {$group : { _id: "$food", max_height: { $max : "$height" } } })


{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Burger",
                "type" : "Veggie"
            },
            "max_height" : 6
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Pizza",
                "type" : "Four Cheeses"
            },
            "max_height" : 6
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: that will include all foods on favorite list, not just top one... Burger is not anyone's top choice in this extremely small data set :)

Answer (score 0):

Since mongoDB version 3.2 You can simply use `$arrayElemAt` and `$max`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {favourite_foods: {$arrayElemAt: ["$favourite_foods", 0]}}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$favourite_foods.name",
      maxHeight: {$max: "$height"}
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GQuf-pVPfNc)