# Group by specific value inside array inside another array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query to group my records by the value inside an array inside another array inside a collection in MongoDB. Now if that doesn't have your head hurting I think a sample schema might be easier to understand:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("...")
    "attributes": [
        [ "attributeA", "valueA" ],
        [ "attributeB", "valueB" ],
        [ "attributeC", "valueC" ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now I want to be able to group my records by the attributeB field based on valueB.

So far I can aggregate if I know the actual value of valueB:

```
collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'attributes': [ "attributeB", "valueB" ] } },
    { '$group': {
        '_id': { 'attributes': [ "attributeB", "valueB" ] } } 
    }  
])
```

Basically seeing if the attributes array contains the pair: [ "attributeB", "valueB" ]. But now I want to be able to have the query determine what valueB is as it performs the aggregation.

To paraphrase: I can't seem to figure out how to group by the value if I don't know the value of valueB. I just want all records to group by their valueB's, when attributeB is found at the first position inside an array inside the attributes array.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your document structure seems to be incorrect though you might have a definite reason for putting it that way. Why not make attributes array :`[{"attributeA":"valueA"},{"attributeB":"valueB"}]` or `"attributes":{"attributeA":"valueA","attributeB":"valueB"}` ? It would make querying a lot easier.

Comment: I didn't want to restrict the data type of an element in the attributes array. It could be anything, not necessarily a key:value pair.

Answer (score 1):

After grouping your data you should use the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)  operator. It pairs up your other fields with every item in the array.

```
collection.aggregate([
  { '$match': { 'attributes': [ "attributeB", "valueB" ] } },
  { '$group': {
      '_id': { 'attributes': [ "attributeB", "valueB" ] } } 
  },
  { '$unwind':  'attributes'},
    ... // here you can match again and continue aggregation
])
```

Most probably this is not the fastest solution. I will think of a better one.

Also note that the order of elements in the array is not preserved.

***UPDATE***

This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055462/group-by-specific-element-of-array-with-mongo-aggregation-framework). So what I would do is create documents in the attribute array like

```
'attributes':[
   {'attribute': 'attributeB', 'value': 'valueB'},
   {'attribute': 'attributeC', 'value': 'valueA'},
]
```

So you can access your `valueB` after the `$match` or `$unwind` through `$value`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it solves another part of the problem I have but not the main one. My main problem is that I don't want my query to match with "valueB" explicitly. I want every instance of "valueB" to be grouped together implicitly by the query.